# Entity Framework MySQL: SQL result different than LINQ result with DateTime condition

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework, datetime

I'm working with Entity Framework on a MySQL database.

I have following LINQ query:

```
          using (var db = new TestDB())
          {
              DateTime limit = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-minutes);
              list = db.Things.Where(t =>
                        //... some other conditions
                        && t.Datetime > limit
                        ).ToList();
          }
```

The LINQ query returns an empty list. But if I check the mysql logging and execute the sql query manually (without any other changes are made to the database), I have the result I would expect. Without the condition on the Datetime, everything works as expected.

The MySQL query generated by the LINQ query:

```
SELECT
`Extent1`.`Volume`
FROM db.`Things` AS `Extent1` 
WHERE /* Other conditions */AND (`Extent1`.`Datetime` > '2014-12-27 23:51:59.224623')
```

So 2 questions:

1. If the SQL query has a result, why does it not get in the list? Does Linq check the conditions a second time? Is this not a major performance issue?
2. What's going wrong with the Datetime-condition? How can I fix this?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Do a count on the table and check if it has any values if not your are probably connecting the wrong database

Comment: If I remove the datetime-condition,  I have the correct results,  so this can't be the problem. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: What is the data type of your `Extent1.Datetime` column?